# How can I control a user-opened browser using either Selenium, Puppeteer, or JS Console Scripts without detection?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

This is necessary to automate a web browser without any hint that it is controlled with automation or testing software. I've tried:

1. Using Selenium with the intended webdriver and default browser executables.
2. Using Selenium with remote-debugging a user browser executable.
3. Implementing countless permutations of option, preference, webdriver modification, and javascript variable setting in and out of the selenium script.

Any ideas?

Comment: There's a lib called undetectable chromedriver to try but if it were me I would switch to Puppeteer

Comment: Does that help your issue?
https://help.applitools.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007189411--Chrome-is-being-controlled-by-automated-test-software-notification

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.